# Are kettlebells swings special?

Tags: kettlebell

Most, or maybe all, kettlebell routines that I see include the swings. Even some trainers who are not hardcore kettlebell fans would recommend it.

Is this exercise special, if yes why?

Comment: What do you mean by “special”?

Comment: You'd be better off asking what the benefits of swings are, or which muscles they work (hint, most of them)

Comment: Related https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25403/what-are-the-target-muscles-of-kettlebell-swings?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *with proper form* it's one of the few exercises that provide both **"aerobic capacity development"** and offers a **"strength training effect"**.  These findings have also been backed by the American College of Sports Medicine.

---

> **Update:** Link #4 is actually a counter argument supporting treadmill over KB aerobic training.  Also found 2 more supporting KB
>   training.

- Kettlebell high-intensity interval training (KB-HIIT) vs Cycling Sprints (SIC)finding that "KB-HIIT may be more attractive and sustainable than SIC and can be effective in stimulating cardiorespiratory and metabolic responses that could improve health and aerobic performance."
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26360962 - *Subscription
  Required*

---

- Found KB training resulted in lower post exercise BP's due to
  increased parasympathetic activity (involving the vagus nerve).
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29016474 -*Subscription
  Required*

---

1. [Comparison of Kettlebell Swings and Treadmill Running at Equivalent Rating of Perceived Exertion Values](https://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Fulltext/2012/05000/Comparison_of_Kettlebell_Swings_and_Treadmill.5.aspx)
2. [Physiological Effects of a Kettlebell Workout versus a High-Resistance Circuit Workout](http://scholarworks.uark.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3691&context=etd)
3. [Comparison of kettlebell swings and treadmill running at equivalent rating of perceived exertion values. *Subscription Required*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22395274)
4. [Are Kettlebells More Effective Than Treadmills](http://www.cissik.com/blog/2012/04/are-kettlebells-more-effective-than-treadmills/)
5. [Comparison of Cardiorespiratory and Metabolic Responses in Kettlebell High-Intensity Interval Training Versus Sprint Interval Cycling.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22395274)
6. [Cardiac Autonomic and Blood Pressure Responses to an Acute Bout of Kettlebell Exercise.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29016474)

Comment: Pretty sure the first and third studies are the same, with the fourth being an analysis of them... might be the way I read it but he (author of the 4th link) didn't sound like a fan of them. Regardless, it does show they provide an aerobic and strength training effect.

Comment: Ha oops... I've read and heard quite a bit about KB swings as a strength based version of cardio. Looks like after attempting to find full text of the 3rd study I ended up posting an article referencing someone who clearly DOES NOT support it (Author #4) oops -- my mistake!

Comment: Well better you post it if it holds value but comes to another conclusion. Otherwise it would be nitpicking

Comment: @Gimli: I don't want to nitpick, but I believe you mean it would be cherry picking.

Comment: Haha you are right, I used the wrong word.